# add multiple geom_density lines by str_detect class in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, stringr

I'd like to be able to overlay multiple lines on a density plot in ggplot, such that Distance is plotted for multiple classes that are detected as substrings?

```
dat<- data.frame(Image = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), 
                 Class = c("A","A:B","A:C","A:D","D:C","B","B:C","A:B","C:D","A:B:C","A:B:C ","A:B:C:D"),
                 Distance = c(1,5,6,2,4,8,9,1,2,3,7,8))
```

for example, I would like for distance of any substring containing class "A" or "B" shown on same plot as separate lines. how would I go about this?

```
dat %>% filter(str_detect(Class,"A")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Distance))+
    geom_density()
```

- 

```
dat %>% filter(str_detect(Class,"B")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Distance))+
    geom_density()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be achieved by using multiple `geom_density` layers where you pass each density layer a filtered dataset. To reduce code duplication my approach uses a helper function and `lapply` to add these density layers by looping over a vector of patterns to include in the plot:

```r
dat<- data.frame(Image = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), 
                 Class = c("A","A:B","A:C","A:D","D:C","B","B:C","A:B","C:D","A:B:C","A:B:C ","A:B:C:D"),
                 Distance = c(1,5,6,2,4,8,9,1,2,3,7,8))

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

make_layer <- function(pattern) {
  dat <- dat %>% 
    filter(str_detect(Class, pattern))
  geom_density(data = dat, aes(color = pattern))
}

patterns <- c("A", "B", "A:B:C")

ggplot(mapping = aes(Distance)) +
  lapply(patterns, make_layer)
```

[image]